# New installation of VS2017 and .net core 2.1 but cannot see templates only set framework

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to set up a new computer with VS2017 to build .net core 2.1 (not 2.2) applications. This is what I've got, all x64:

- Visual Studio Enterprise 2017: 15.9.22
- dotNet core sdk 2.1.513 (edit from: 2.1.805)
- enabled the flag in VS to allow SDK previews

NOTE: As per first answer I erroneously used a 2019 version of SDK, but I swapped this 2.1.805 with 2.1.513 (the 2017 version) and this fails too

I can compile and build fine, but when I try VS2017

1. There are no .net core templates
2. Compiling existing core projects created from command line is ok
3. Opening a project created from the command line says

I've tried various online solutions but they all seem to stem from people using old versions trying out .net core 2 when it was released as a beta. I'm doing everything from the latest versions.

Can anyone help me get VS provide templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try reading the [downloads page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fair enough I failed on that part of the reading :)

But I previously downloaded 2.1.513 and it didn't work so uninstalled and tried the latest version just in case.

i.e. 2.1.513 does not work either.

Comment: I think it might have been an ordering thing and i installed the sdk before visual studio. But it compiles inside VS now, I just cannot get it to show the templates. I'll update my question to be more specific. Thanks.